# Combining Dictionaries w/o overwriting

Tags: python

I am trying to combine dictionaries into a single dictionary while retaining previous values.

I have provided an example code below. Ideally, I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
dict3 = {"dict1" : {"North America" : "United States" , "Europe" : "France" , "Asia" : "China" }, "dict2" : {"North America" : "Canada" , "Europe" : "Spain" , "Asia" : "Japan"}}
```

```
dict1 = {"North America" : "United States" , "Europe" : "France" , "Asia" : "China"}
dict2 = {"North America" : "Canada" , "Europe" : "Spain" , "Asia" : "Japan"}
dict3 = {}
targetdict = {"dict1" : {"North America" : "United States" , "Europe" : "France" , "Asia" : "China" }, "dict2" : {"North America" : "Canada" , "Europe" : "Spain" , "Asia" : "Japan"}}

dict3.update(dict1)
print(dict3)
dict3.update(dict2)
print(dict3)
```

I want to dict3 to be the same as the targetdict. So effectively print(dict3) would be the same result as print(targetdict).

I would be looking to add many potential dictionaries to the 'dict3' variable and all of the dictionaries could have "North America" as a key for example. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your dictionaries are nested so I don't see how they could overwrite each other. Why is the could have "North America" as a key relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use:

```
dict3['dict1'] = dict1
dict3['dict2'] = dict2
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not directly define dict3 from the other two ?

```
dict3 = {"dict1":dict1, "dict2":dict2}
```